OpenAPI - Create Constant Strings for Java
How do I create constants in Open Api Yaml? The constants will be placed in a Java class for use. The following Open API Yaml is not working:
Java
public static final String BOOK = "book_sample";
public static final String Car = "car_test";

OpenAPI Yaml Attempt
components:
  constants:
    BOOK: "book_sample"
    CAR: "car_test"


There are no constants in OpenAPI Specifications like that, components.constants is not a valid property - source. If you provide what version of OpenAPI you are using, perhaps there are some known workarounds?

you can do something like this for OAS 3.0.x which uses a variation of JSON Schema draft-04
openapi: 3.0.4
info:
  title: test
  version: 0.0.1
components:
  book:
    enum:
    - book_sample
  car:
    enum:
    - car_test


for OAS 3.1.x which uses JSON Schema 2020-12
openapi: 3.1.1
info:
  title: test
  version: 0.0.1
components:
  book:
    const: book_sample
  car:
    const: car_test

